# Template for creating empty groups in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to create a template for creating empty groups in Project Navigator?

for example, I use MVVM design pattern in my applications, so I have modules lets say Login and inside I like to create groups like following: Models, ViewModels, Views. So every time I create a new module I have to create those groups manually.

[image]

So I thought if someone had found a workaround or maybe there is a shortcut to duplicate the group?

Thanks in Advance.